# AWS Get Pre-Sign URL always show ExpiredToken when download file

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I have working Java code to get pre-sign URL for uploading files to s3:

```
    String objectKey = "folder/fileName.pdf";
    Date expiration = new Date();
    long expTimeMillis = expiration.getTime();
    expTimeMillis += 1000 * 60 * 15;//15 minutes
    expiration.setTime(expTimeMillis);

    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(S3_BUCKET_NAME, objectKey)
            .withMethod(HttpMethod.PUT)
            .withExpiration(expiration);
    URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);

    return url.toString()
```

this code works, it produces url that I can put in Postman, run Put request and get response, also it works on our prod servers. Now I need code to download the same file. I tried to use same code, the only difference - I used GET method instead of PUT:

```
.withMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
```

it produces URL:

```
https://bucketName.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/folder/fileName.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASDFABASDF%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220527T034939Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Security-Token=FwoAdFASDFAOBASDsdfSF%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaDM69O7O54EA7PUeu0yLSARm%2Bduy8vQQtmA7yyvWutiSNLuosByvxyN%2BGZUxmI12r0HdqqRbrwAr1k9bj%2FJEDeEGD3MDpt6%2Bwh9XjoLwyUsUCk7Iah1zPakr%2BDe6%2BNMntjPIS%2BbxXvgttumg0aLG4WDbWE9k40M5HpbJ5YJLjHwI0IB5zF4A9Oq4KrIUWiYhEM4lEVbGCHKoS3nxNnYh1eqSmx2rMHE%2FPFsKPMVL0FUj1bDV3AHzxFwTb6JuKP5A4YGdSsogiH4BGpcZLxUGKohBAqMCjY9IyIBjIrGDHqlsb2p7wvYKtlQPd%2FsEeB%2BAwACfCZhAJ4X45IOTVlowo7AdsnWtogsg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Signature=5ab6e616sdfsaf0a6412a68a40f776f26d9ea8f8c136a78874baa7c
```

But when I paste it in browser I have an error:

```
<Error>
     <Code>ExpiredToken</Code>
     <Message>The provided token has expired.</Message>
     <Token-0>aVDSAFVdzEKH//////////wEaDM69O7O54EASDF ASDF;LJ ;AS DFGZUxmI12r0HdqqRbrwAr1k9bj/JEDeEGD3MDpt6+wh9XjoLwyUsUCk7Iah1zPakr+De6+NMntjPIS+bxXvgttumg0aLG4WDbWE9k40M5HpbJ5YJLjHwI0IB5zF4ADF32E/PFsKPMVL0FUj1bDV3AHzxFwTb6JuKP5A4YGdSsogiH4BGpcZLxUGKohBAqMCjY9adsf#2SDFsEeB+AwACfCZhAJ4X45IOTVlowo7AdsnWtogsg==</Token-0>
     <RequestId>EX3Q0KY8BT4HDFASDF234</RequestId>
     <HostId>SiSQsVjDiGpTmWqECybt0nob#xdASDFRIXVJNUG+cmmkI7bHBy6lUejXL5HvchpSCbj0U= 
     </HostId>
</Error>
```

I added expiration time and had same result.
Next I tried to out put data:

```
    System.out.println(generatePresignedUrlRequest.getBucketName());
    System.out.println(generatePresignedUrlRequest.getMethod());
    System.out.println(generatePresignedUrlRequest.getExpiration());
    System.out.println(generatePresignedUrlRequest.getContentType());
    System.out.println(generatePresignedUrlRequest.getKey());
```

And I got result:

```
    bucketName
    GET
    Thu Jun 02 23:25:21 GMT 2022
    null
    folder/fileName.pdf
```

Today is May 26, so it should not be expired.
I tried to run console command:

```
aws s3 presign s3://bucketName/folder/fileName.pdf --expires-in 604800 --region us-west-2
```

it produces same URL as above. When I paste this url in browser I have same error as above.
What am I doing wrong? how to fix it? how to generate Pre-Sign URL to download file from S3?

Comment: Is your system clock correct?

Comment: You appear to be using different code from what you've shown, the expired time is 7 days.  If you're signing in a Lambda or other environment with an instance profile, then [your signed URL won't function for the full 7 days](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/presigned-url-s3-bucket-expiration/).